# How to get environment variable from a core dump

Tags: gdb

In UNIX environment(linux/solaris/AIX) my application crashing. Please help to me get environment variable from the core dump

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Running `strings -a core` should produce an obvious-looking block of strings like `HOME=...`, `HOSTNAME=...`, etc.

You can also examine initial environment by looking at the 3rd argument to `main`, which is a `envp[]` -- a `NULL`-terminated array of pointers to the environment strings.

Finally, *current* environment block is pointed at by `__environ` or similar variable.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the answer provided by @employed-russian, newer versions of the GDB debugger have the [pipe](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Shell-Commands.html) command.

That makes it easier to find specific elements of an array of strings.

For example, to find the processes current working directory at the time of the crash:

```
(gdb) pipe print *__environ@1000 | grep '"PWD='
  0xffc145e4 "PWD=/home/blother",
```

or to sort the list of environment variables:

```
(gdb) pipe p -array on -- *__environ@1000 | awk -F\" '{print $2}' | sort
```

The `array on` flag ensures that each element is printed on its own output line. The `--` delimits options from arguments in the standard fashion. The `awk` -F option specifies a delimiter.